# Using Multiple "Select" inside the GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

What I am trying to do is have a grid view with 3 "select" and I renamed them to edit , delete and details

and each one should redirect to a certain page

my question , how I can know which column or "Select" the user clicked

Thanks

Comment: How did you create the buttons/links? Is it a CommandField? Have you generated things manually, or renamed autogenerated commands?

Comment: its from the commandfield (select)

Comment: Make sure that your buttons/links are of different types. There are built in buttons/links for edit, delete and select that are suitable to use. Just set `ShowEditButton="true"` to display it. The text displayed can be customized.

Comment: the edit and delete are just links to other page :)

Answer (score 1):

Set the `CommandName` property of your buttons. Then add an event handler for the `RowCommand` event of the gridview:

```
protected void MyGrid_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
  switch(e.CommandName)
  {
    case "SomeCommand":
      Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx");
      break;
    case "OtherCommand":
      Respone.Redirect("OtherPage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay , any possible way I can send the datakey to the page , for example  `Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx"+MyGrid.SelectedValue);`
is not working , THanks

Answer (score 0):

```
string commandName = e.CommandName.ToString().Trim();
  GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];
  switch (commandName)
  {
      case "showName":                   
          LClickName.Text = "You Clicked Show Name Button : \"" + row.Cells[1].Text + "\"";                   
          break;
      case "EditName":                   
          LClickName.Text = "You Clicked Edit Name Button : \"" + row.Cells[1].Text + "\"";                  
          break;
      default: break;
  }
```

Here is a sample for Multiple select Button in One Gridview

[Multiple Select Button In One Gridview](http://www.developersnote.com/2014/01/multiple-select-button-in-one-gridview.html)